# Cmake install header without a specific method

Tags: header, installation, cmake, shared-libraries

I have a small library that I made that is stand along except for one optional method in a class that requires Imagemagick. So I am looking to make it possible to not compile that method if the machine does not have Imagemagick installed; rather then simply failing. The only issue is that the header will still have that method defined (though it was not compiled). Is there a way to remove that method from the header using Cmake or some other approach?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the definition in a preprocessor definition:

```
#ifdef HAVE_IMAGEMAGICK
  void myFunctionDefinition(void);
#endif
```

Then, in CMake, if ImageMagick is found, add a definition to the project.  CMake will pass that definition to the command line of the compiler, which will define the preprocessor token.

```
IF(IMAGEMAGICK_FOUND)  # or whatever CMake variable holds this info
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DHAVE_IMAGEMAGICK)
ENDIF()
```

Alternatively, if you have many such defines, you could consider an include file to hold all of these configurations.  The CMake command CONFIGURE_FILE can then expand out an entire file's worth of configuration statements all at once.

Comment: While that will work building the library, it would not remove that declaration in the headers. So IDEs still detect that method's existence, even thought it is defined out. For the moment I simply created an exception and throw it if called when Imagemagick is not compiled in. Good input though :)